# Is there a way to get URI of bitmap without saving it to sdcard?

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, android-bitmap

I am making an app that allows the user to share an image using android intent but how to get that URI of

a bitmap without need to saving it to sd card

I have used this code that works fine, but I don't need to save this bitmap to sd card

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
          ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
          String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "title", null);
          return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

I need to get that URI without saving that bitmap to sd card

Comment: you mean "You want to get the Uri of In-Memory Bitmap"??

Comment: @Sagar Pilkhwal i want to get the uri of bitmap to share it but i dont need to save it to internal or external storage ... is that possible ?

Comment: No its not possible, you will have to save the file on to the SD card and then share it and then delete the file

Comment: @Sagar Pilkhwal when i can know if the user have shared the image or not to delete it after the process have finished ?

Comment: i have post an answer, try it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void ShareImage(Intent intent) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(mImageUrl);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(mActivity, image));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, 1001));
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    //check for result is OK and then check for your requestCode(1001) and then delete the file

}
```

Comment: yes that is what i need thank you ... i dont know why this method goes from my mind :D .. thank you again.

Comment: Now you will remember it henceforward... :)

Comment: You are completely forgetting about the byte array you are creating. How can this even work?

Comment: and then delete the file... Can u explain how to delete the file ?

Comment: This answer is interesting

Comment: This will create duplicate of the image that is in the `mImageUrl`. Where is the deletion part? This is not the complete answer

Comment: @NullByte08 were you able to find a solution which creates a temp image or delete it afterwards?

Comment: @RedM I have answered below, please check if it helps. This was a long time back so I don't remember the actual issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
protected void tryToShareImage(Intent intent) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(mImageUrl);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(mActivity, image));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using..."));
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

after that You can delete files using `File.delete()`

Comment: when i can delete this file i dont know when the user can choose to share if i delete the file after start intent the uri dont found

Comment: When file uploaded successfully then you can delete file. If you are using AsyncTask then in onPostExecute you can delete.

Answer (score -1):

Accepted answer is not working for me. Maybe I missed something from that. But, every time I get the uri of the bitmap, it is saved in local storage. I couldnt find a way to delete that (extra) saved bitmap in accepted answer.
I am using the following way:

First, get the uri of the bitmap:

```
public static Uri getUri(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Then, delete the (extra) saved bitmap:

```
this.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

PS: Above code for deletion is for Activity. If you want to delete inside a Fragment, use this:

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```