# how to load bitmap directly with picasso library like following

Tags: java, picasso

```
Picasso.with(context).load("url").into(imageView);
```

Here instead of url i want bitmap how can i achieve this.
like below-

```
Picasso.with(context).load(bitmap).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 23):

This should work for you.
Use the returned URI with Picasso.

(taken from: [is there away to get uri of bitmap with out save it to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059748/is-there-away-to-get-uri-of-bitmap-with-out-save-it-to-sdcard))

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: Although it works it's not the best solution because it needs "write to storage" permission.

Comment: moreover, the image will stay in the device storage forever if you don't clean it up

Answer (score 9):

**My Kotlin solution**

create the bitmap from data

```
    val inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.data)
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
```

**IMPORTANT:** **if you don't need to store** the image you can avoid Picasso and load the image right away

```
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

otherwise store the file and load it with Picasso

```
    val jpegData = stream.toByteArray()

    val file = File(cacheDir, "filename.jpg")
    file.createNewFile()

    val fileOS = FileOutputStream(file)
    fileOS.write(jpegData)
    fileOS.flush()
    fileOS.close()

    Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(file.path)).into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private void loadBitmapByPicasso(Context pContext, Bitmap pBitmap, ImageView pImageView) {
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(File.createTempFile("temp_file_name", ".jpg", pContext.getCacheDir()));
        OutputStream outputStream = pContext.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        pBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        Picasso.get().load(uri).into(pImageView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("LoadBitmapByPicasso", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

Answer (score 0):

If you have bitmap, then no need to load using picasso, there is simple solution provided by android, you can use below code

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bimap);
```

Answer (score -3):

You are using an old version of Picasso.

Update the version in your Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Java:

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.get().load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.get().load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

[See more details on the Picasso website](http://square.github.io/picasso/)