# how to change image file name in android studio?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

**I am downloading an image from URL and displaying on an imageview but the problem is if image name starts with a digit it can't be displayed.**

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //loading.dismiss();

        String image_name = result.toString();
        if( Character.isDigit(image_name.charAt(0))){

        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: First show your code then will give you solution.

Comment: Only your code will tell the actual solution for the problem

Comment: I have edited the question. code have been added

Comment: i want to change image name inside this code block. if( Character.isDigit(image_name.charAt(0))){

        }

Comment: Share your image url which contains digit code.

Comment: https://static.scanhalal.com/work/555.jpg @Piyush

Comment: it should not depend on the image name. The problem is likely somewhere else

Comment: I have tested other images from the same URL they worked fine, only images start with a digit not displaying.

Comment: thank you, the issue is resolved, @VladyslavMatviienko you're right the issue is not due to digit. URL returns null

Answer (score 1):

Since code provided is unclear, so this might help you.
Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load Image on ImageView
or save bitmap to sdCard and then load it
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34629526/5057663

Comment: this likely should be a comment, not an answer, because it actually *does not answer the question*, while still is usefull

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Upvoted your comment, you're absolutely right. But he can't comment as he has only 15 reps.. He needs atleast 50 to comment :)